# Summing Sub-categories within a category

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and wanted to check if something like this is possible to do in it.

I have production data from sub-blocks in an excel table, for example:

table 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NZzs.jpg

I have another table which shows how the sub-blocks are combined into bigger blocks:

table 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxaUE.jpg

I want to be able to create a table that sums the sub-blocks and show the total production for the bigger blocks, for example:

table 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIh7H.jpg

If we give Tableau Tables 1 and 2 as input, is it possible for Tableau to output the third table?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then you don't need table 2.

Take table 1 in tableau then create 3 calculated fields:

Calcualted field1 `Block1`

```
[Sub-Block A]+[Sub-Block B]
```

Calcualted field1 `Block1`

```
[Sub-Block C]+[Sub-Block D]+[Sub-Block E]
```

Calcualted field1 `Block3`

```
[Sub-Block F]+[Sub-Block G]
```

Place these on the sheet

Comment: Thanks, you did understand the problem correctly. However, ultimately my goal is to use Table 2. The idea is that if I change the mapping in Table 2, i.e. change the assignment of sub-blocks to the blocks, then Tableau should update Table 3 accordingly.